# jQuery: How to pass value from one function to another?

Tags: jquery

UPDATE:

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to figure out (see the question in the comment):

```
        $("document").ready(function() {
        $("#startDate").datepicker({

            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var dateAsObject = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
                var timestamp = dateAsObject.getTime(); // the timestamp of the date picked by user
            }
        });

        // how do I get the value of timestamp to show up here?
        // It also needs to update every time onSelect changes the value.
        alert(timestamp);

    });
```

---

Comment: You dont need to have two ` $(document).ready(function() {})` fucntions. Put all the functionality you want inside one.

Comment: Functions in jquery are just javascript functions. Jquery is just a bunch of syntax sugar to make you life a little easier when it comes to events. Your ready event handlers are just that. They handle when the page loads and get called first come first serve. In your first ready handler you are setting up a date picker and the second you are setting up a clock. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I know that I don't need 2 document.ready but if I put them into one it doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose you want to select a date (timestamp) with the first datepicker plugin, and then use that value in the second plugin somehow. But what do you want to use it for, currentDate, pastDate, or something else entirely? Also, what do you want to do with this value while the user has nothing selected yet? So what is the initial state of the second plugin? And should it update if the datepicker changes? You see, a lot of things to think about...

Comment: As explained above, I need to pass "timestamp" to the other function i.e. I need to replace "pastDate.getTime()" with the value of "timestamp".

Comment: The entire "pastDate.getTime()" needs to be replaced with the value of "timestamp".

Comment: Yes, upon input from datepicker timestamp will automatically update. I just need to pass that timestamp to the other function now.

Comment: I'm guessing this is one of those scenarios where a JavaScript closure would do the job. But I'm not sure how to do it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an asynchronous flow, you'll have to work with events.

Something like this should probably work:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

     function setClock(startTime) {
        return $('.clock').FlipClock(
            (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 - startTime, 
            {
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter'
            }
        );
    }


    $("#startDate").datepicker({

        // ... all your (here irrelevant) options ...

        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            // I assume this is an event handler that gets called every time your date changes. 
            // Here you have to update the timestamp on your second plugin.
            setClock($(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ).getTime());
    });

    // initiate the clock
    setClock((new Date(2017, 8, 11)).getTime());

});
```

So first I declare a function that can set up the clock with a provided date. I then set up the datepicker, and it its (assumed) change handler I tell it to update the clock with the newly selected date. Finally I initiate the clock so it already shows something before the user has selected a date (you should probably use that same date as start value for your datepicker).

Ideally you would update the clock on change in stead of re-initiating it, but I have no idea of the plugins API supports this. I have no idea if any of this actually works, since I don't know the actual plugins and have no way to test. I hope it points you in the right direction though. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: Hmm... I need to do it the other way around. Only if/when the user enters the date (via datepicker) should the clock be initiated. That would also automatically mean that every change to the input/datepicker would initiate a brand new clock with the correct value from the user input.

Comment: So, my hardcoded date should be ignored. That's from a different project. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: just skip the last line then, don't initiate on page load, only in the event handler

Comment: Hmm.. this isn't really working for me. I've just updated my question with the simplified version of what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: You are still not taking the asynchronous flow into account. At the time you alert the timestamp, the user has not yet selected a date, so you'll probably get an `undefined`. You really need to put that logic in the onSelect function. Feel free to set up a working fiddle with what you got so far, and I'll be happy to show you how to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

If both function are in same file you can directly use variable 
`var timestamp`  as it is define globally .
IF you are calling from separate file you can use `<script >` Tag to call variable in other file .

Comment: you are not taking the async flow into account. Also, suggesting a global as a solution, really...

Comment: I had certainly tried that (among other things) before posting here. That didn't work.

Comment: @Pevara Yep, I also thought that making it global wouldn't be a good idea. (although I had tried it anyway but couldn't get it to work)